# Encrypt login and password in sqlite database - SHA 256 in C#

Tags: c#, encryption

I want to store login and password in sqlite database. This database in encrypted using SQLCipher library. But password to encrypt database is separate issue. This password is stored in code of application. Login and password are provided by user to login to application. In C# there is the SHA256 class. If I use this class if it is enough ? Or rather I should use hash and salt or other methods ?

Thanks

Comment: You should hash + salt users passwords.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To store a user password in a database for login matters, you should use a hash function with a salt.

`SHA 256` is one of them, but there are better ones existing. I recommend you using the [`PBKDF2`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2) derivative function. You can implement your own `PBKDF2` hashing method using the [`Rfc2898DeriveBytes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes.aspx) class provided in the .NET framework.

Here is a quick *how-to-do-it*:

```
int saltSize = 256;     // Number of bytes of the salt
int iterations = 1000;  // Number of times we iterate the function
                        // The more we iterate, the more it is gonna take time.
                        //     The advantage of a great iterations number is to 
                        //     make brutforce attack more painful.
int hashSize = 20;      // Number of bytes of the hash (the output)

var deriveBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes("mypassword", saltSize, iterations);
byte[] salt = deriveBytes.Salt;
byte[] hash = deriveBytes.GetBytes(hashSize);
```

You just have now to store the salt and the hash in your database. Use [`Convert.FromBase64String`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string.aspx) and [`Convert.ToBase64String`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524.aspx) to get a `string` from a `byte[]` and vice-versa.

---

Another alternative is to use [`bcrypt`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt). See this interesting [article](http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/).

Comment: How do you store both the salt and the hash in the password column in the database?

Comment: @Tris You store them in two different columns.