# Restrict SHA-1 hash algorithm to produce hashing within 24-bits, C#

Tags: c#, sha1

I was wondering if there is an  implementation of SHA-1 hashing in C#, that restricts the hashing output to 24bits? As far as I have seen (hopefully not missing a point) in the .NET version of SHA-1, we cannot restrict it.
Not necessary that I need SHA-1, any algorithm would work, but the restriction is important.

Any pointers or guidance is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Could you state the requirement for such short hash? Cryptographic hashing algorithms from SHA family have minimal hash length of 160 bits. Cryptographic hashing with shortest output I'm aware of is MD5 - but it still produces 128-bit hashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the PBKDF2 algorithm. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8218200/825024).

Note that a 24 bits hash seems poor, but it depends on what you intend to do with it.